# LPR Error "Unknown Printer"

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, cups-lpd

I am trying to complete the final step for install my Brother QL-1060N printer in terminal.  The command works fine in `Ubuntu 18.04`:

```
lpr -P QL -1060N -o raw pdt5030a.bin
```

According the `man` there is no "-o" option for `lpr` in **Ubuntu Studio 20.04**.  When I do the above command the output is

```
usage: lpr [-cdfghlmnpqrstv] [-#num] [-1234 font] [-C class] [-i [numcols]]
    [-J job] [-Pprinter] [-T title] [-U user] [-wnum] [name ...]
```

Simply dropping `-o raw` gives me the error

```
lpr: QL-1060N: unknown printer
```

I also received the **unknown printer** error when I try

```
lpr -P "QL-1060N" pdt5030a.bin
```

I used `TAB` so **Ubuntu Studio 20.04** would tell me the available options:

```
ENVY_Photo_7800      ENVY_Photo_7800_fax  hp_LaserJet_1012     QL-1060N             QL-1060N-2
```

With **QL-1060N** looking the same I did `sudo nano /etc/cups/printers.conf` to check for white space.  None exists.

I don't understand what syntax I am suppose to give.  The "read me" file I'm referring to is included in the [CUPSwrapper printer driver (deb package)](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=ca&lang=en&prod=ql1060neus&os=130&dlid=dlfp002234_000&flang=178&type3=592)

The output for `lpstat -t` is

```
system default destination: QL-1060N-2
device for ENVY_Photo_7800: hp:/net/ENVY_Photo_7800_series?ip=10.1.1.19
device for ENVY_Photo_7800_fax: hpfax:/net/ENVY_Photo_7800_series?ip=10.1.1.19
device for hp_LaserJet_1012: hp:/net/hp_LaserJet_1012?ip=10.1.1.15
device for QL-1060N: socket://10.1.1.14
device for QL-1060N-2: usb://Brother/QL-1060N?serial=C9G224418
ENVY_Photo_7800 accepting requests since Tue 21 Jul 2020 07:17:42 PM
ENVY_Photo_7800_fax accepting requests since Tue 21 Jul 2020 07:16:26 PM
hp_LaserJet_1012 accepting requests since Fri 21 Aug 2020 08:09:08 PM
QL-1060N accepting requests since Mon 24 Aug 2020 04:35:01 PM
QL-1060N-2 accepting requests since Mon 24 Aug 2020 12:48:37 AM
printer ENVY_Photo_7800 is idle.  enabled since Tue 21 Jul 2020 07:17:42 PM
printer ENVY_Photo_7800_fax is idle.  enabled since Tue 21 Jul 2020 07:16:26 PM
printer hp_LaserJet_1012 is idle.  enabled since Fri 21 Aug 2020 08:09:08 PM
printer QL-1060N is idle.  enabled since Mon 24 Aug 2020 04:35:01 PM
printer QL-1060N-2 is idle.  enabled since Mon 24 Aug 2020 12:48:37 AM
```

Comment: `lpstat -t`, `man lpstat`.

Comment: @waltinator I updated my question with the output for this.  There is a USB and network version of this printer.  10.1.1.14 is the network version; "QL-1060N-2" is the USB version